# Why is Framework7 is not working in my Cordova app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, html-framework-7

I am developing a mobile app with Cordova and I have framework7 library in my template. Everything works smoothly on the Cordova browser platform. However, when I run it on the iOS platform, my menu links do not work.

There is no console error output.

My `app.js` :

```
// Dom7
        var $ = Dom7;

        // Init App
        var app = new Framework7({
            root: '#app',
            theme: 'ios',
            routes: routes,
            view: {
                pushState: false,
            },
        });

        app.sheet.create({
            el: '.my-sheet-swipe-to-close',
            swipeToClose: true,
            backdrop: true,
        });


        var mainView = app.views.create('.view-main', {
            url: './index.html'
        });
```

My `routes.js` :

```
"use strict";
var routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    Url: './index.html',
  },

  {
    path: '/ads/',
    url: './ads.html',
  },

  {
    path: '/ads-details/',
    url: './ads-details.html',
  },

  {
    path: '/add-ads/',
    url: './add-ads.html',
  },
  //more...
];
```

My `index.html` :

```
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/my-ads/" data-transition="f7-dive" class="item-link item-content panel-close">
        <div class="item-media">
          <ion-icon name="duplicate-outline" class="color-blue"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="item-title">My Ads</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <!-- more... -->
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- more... -->
<!-- script -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/framework7.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- end script -->
```

I tried uninstalling framework7, this time when I ran the application I didn't get any images because index.html was not loaded.

I bought the theme through *themeforest*, I tried to contact the seller, but he didn't fill in anything for communication, I guess he stopped providing support, I can't contact him in any way.

Furthermore, I looked at the documentation of the theme, nothing is mentioned in the subject.